# Hymn written by Maharishi Bodhayan for lord Rama?

Tags: rama, sita, ramnandacharya

Which hymn is written by Maharishi Bodhayan for Lord Rāma?

Answer (score 1):

A Hymn by Maharishi Bodhayan (Purushöttamāchārya) for Lord Rama

**सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।**

रामिति बीजवान् नाथ मन्त्रराजो हि तारकः
तं जपामि तब प्रीत्यै पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥ १ ॥

राम ! दोनोऽनुकूलोऽहं विश्वस्तोऽप्रातिकूल्यवान् ।
त्वयि न्यस्यामि चात्मानं पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥२॥

मामनाथे स्वशेषं च न्यासितं स्वार्थमेव हि ।
निर्भरं स्वभरत्वेन पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥३॥

यस्मिन् देहेऽहमानीतः कर्मणा स्वेन राघव ! ।
तदन्ते देहि सायुज्यं पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥४॥

न गतिजनकीनाथ! त्वां बिना परमेश्वर ।
परां गति प्रपन्नं त्वां पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥५॥

मोहितो मायया तेऽहं दैव्या गुणविशिष्टया ।
शरण्यं त्वां प्रपन्नोऽस्मि पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥६॥

End of **Purushöttamā Prapattishatkam** by Maharishi Bodhayan (Purushöttamāchārya)